# How to use pastebin API with python?[specific error]

Tags: python, pastebin

I'm trying to use the pastebin api with docs: python https://pastebin.com/doc_api. Using the urllib library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html.

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse

def main():

    def pastebinner():
        site = 'https://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php'
        dev_key = 
        code = "12345678910, test"      
        our_data = urllib.parse.urlencode({"api_dev_key": dev_key, "api_option": "paste", "api_paste_code": code})  
        our_data = our_data.encode()                    
        resp = urllib.request.urlopen(site, our_data)
        print(resp.read())
        
    pastebinner()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here's the error i get:

> File "C:\Program
> Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py",
> line 214, in urlopen
> return opener.open(url, data, timeout)   File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py",
> line 523, in open
> response = meth(req, response)   File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py",
> line 632, in http_response
> response = self.parent.error(   File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py",
> line 561, in error
> return self._call_chain(*args)   File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py",
> line 494, in _call_chain
> result = func(*args)   File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py",
> line 641, in http_error_default
> raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp) urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 422: Unprocessable entity

Any ideas regarding the reason for getting this error?

bump: I still have no idea please help.
bump2: :v

Comment: @Nearoo why does that make the request unparseable? api_paste_code should be the content of the paste right? from the docs:

`Creating A New Paste, [Required Parameters]
Include all the following POST parameters when you request the url:

1. api_dev_key - which is your unique API Developers Key.
2. api_option - set as paste, this will indicate you want to create a new paste.
3. api_paste_code - this is the text that will be written inside your paste.

Leaving any of these parameters out will result in an error.`

Comment: Right :) Makes no sense, sorry.

Comment: @Nearoo There's a more user friendly python library but I really dont want to use it because urllib is part of the standard library. Based on some reading I've done it seems like possible pastebin thinks im a bout and thats the reason why. But what do i put in my code to fix this? I know you may not know but I think that's the question here.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `urllib.request.urlopen(site, our_data)` which is an HTTP GET ([default](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.Request) for anything in urllib). You need to do an HTTP POST instead. [Obligatory w3 link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)

Please note that the code below is untested

```py
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse


def main():

    def pastebinner():
        site = 'https://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php'
        dev_key = 'APIKEYGOESHERE'
        code = "12345678910, test"
        our_data = urllib.parse.urlencode({"api_dev_key": dev_key, "api_option": "paste", "api_paste_code": code})
        our_data = our_data.encode()
        request = urllib.request.Request(site, method='POST')
        resp = urllib.request.urlopen(request, our_data)
        print(resp.read())

    pastebinner()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The error is very unhelpful. I mean, why not return a [teapot response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/418) instead?

Answer (score 0):

leaving this here in case anyone else runs into this issue. Not 100% sure about this, will test later DONT USE URLLIB2 USE httplib2. I believe that will fix your problem.